# Does the Business Logic Layer handle View Models in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, model, viewmodel

I have an application with 4 projects

- **Presentation**
- **BLL**
- **Models**
- **DA**

Should the BLL be passing and retrieving View Models to and from the Presentation Layer. (And handle all mapping)

Or rather should it only deal with Domain Models and let the Presentation Layer (Controller) handle all mappings.

Thanks

Comment: why do you want to delete VM?

Comment: Not delete, just shift to another project.  If I kept it in the Presentation layer and the BLL referenced them (the Presentation layer is already referencing the BLL) a circular dependency would exist which isn't valid.

Comment: Your VM should have reference to BLL not opposite.  So now the question is why your BLL needs VM reference?

Comment: I understand, my Presentation layer / VM layer is currently only referencing the BLL, NOT the other way around.  However, that would be the case if I wanted the BLL to create VM objects and handle them.  That is why I said to move the VM to another project and let the BLL reference it from there.

Comment: I am going to restructure my question so it is easier to understand. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing absolute about your development approach. you could choose what suits you in any case. But you should consider your future maintenance and extension possibilities when you choose you approach. Based on details you provided, I think you should consider some issues:

- User input verification: verification on user input isn't part of you BLL. So if you connect you presentation to BLL, you will mix both and it makes it hard to manage your code or "separation on concerns"
- In mvc case you always use data annotation for presentation. Using BLL for VM probably makes it hard to use them.
- On presentation layer, you need tools like CSS and Jquery. Using them with BLL, probably makes your code very messy and hard to
  maintain later.
- For any even minor change on your presentation, you need to change your BLL which is against all principals!.
- It will be hard to provide services like WebApi for clients, if you intermingled you BLL with presentation.
- BLL access from views, makes life easier for hackers!.

and lots more!.

Comment: Thanks, the point where changing the VM should not need me to touch the BLL sold it for me!