# is it bad to use the repository directly into the controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Have a layered ASP.NET MVC project:

- DAL (or repository).
- Service.
- Controller.

In DAL I have a class like:

```
public class CatRepository : ICatRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Cat> GetAll()
    { // Some implementation
    }
}
```

In controller I just want to return all cats without any additional logic, so I can directly call CatRepository.GetAll(). This is bad? Should I create a service (wrapper) class for CatRepository without any logic and invoke methods from there?

Comment: More importantly, why do you *think* this approach may be bad?  Why do you *think* an alternate approach may be better?  What actual problem are you seeing that may need to be solved?  There's nothing *inherently* wrong with any design, unless it introduces a problem.

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35306554/3743442 .